# how to cache files in chrome

Tags: apache-httpd, chrome, cache

I have a web application in that i want some of the files should always be cached like for atleast 24 hours in chrome browser. For that i have done some configuration in my apache webserver 2.4.9.

But still my files are getting cached. It always gets downloaded from my web server.

Any idea how to do setting in apache or chrome for enabling browser cache in chrome because it is working properly in Mozilla browser.

Also I want to know I have already set my cache-control to 1 day but still in chrome it is showing no-cache

My apache configuration settings.

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|png|js|css)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

Ouput in browser netpanel

```
Remote Address:xx.xx.xx.xx:80
Request URL:http://test.com/test.js?buildInfo=1.1.2
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
**Cache-Control:no-cache**
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=169A6E41C963E44F2D9D2FA405E41A08
Host:xx.xx.xxx.xx
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://test.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like    
Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
buildInfo:1.1.2
Response Headersview source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/javascript
Date:Wed, 22 Oct 2014 05:02:31 GMT
ETag:W/"7792381-1413890396000-gzip"
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=88
Last-Modified:Tue, 21 Oct 2014 11:19:56 GMT
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: I guess that `?buildInfo=1.1.2` querystring is the culprit. Can you get rid off that parameter and try?

Comment: Did you mean _still my files are **not** getting cached_?

Comment: Yes now i have changed my file extension to test.js removed the buildInfo part. Also I have used

Comment: Also I have set ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 months"

Comment: Now net panel shows proper expiry header after 1 month also max-age is after 1 month but still chrome is not caching the files.

Comment: The request still goes to my server.    Response that I am getting                                               Accept-Ranges:none
Cache-Control:max-age=2592000
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/javascript
Date:Thu, 23 Oct 2014 06:51:03 GMT
Expires:Sat, 22 Nov 2014 06:51:03 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=92
Last-Modified:Wed, 22 Oct 2014 12:30:30 GMT
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding